# Batch rename part of a file in windows

Tags: windows, file-management

Is there a tool for easily renaming a part of the filename for a batch of files in one go?

For instance if I have:

- foo_bar 1.jpg
- foo_bar 2.jpg

let's say I want to remove the underscore to get the following:

- foo bar 1.jpg
- foo bar 2.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [how-can-i-mass-rename-files-in-dos](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-in-dos) question asked about an hour after mine I have actually found a really good free tool that does exactly what I want: [bulkrenameutility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) it is a free rename utility. It is kind of confusing at first, but I like the preview mode, and it can do regular expressions, seems very powerful!

Answer (score 10):

In the command window:

```
REN foo_bar*.jpg "foo bar*.jpg"
```

Comment: Hey REN was more powerful than I though. However I notice that only works if the results is the same length. For instance: 
REN foo_bar*.jpg "pic*.jpg" results in files called "pic_bar1.jpg" rather than what I would want i.e. "pic1.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

There's a freeware [file renamer utility](http://www.webxpace.com/software/freeware.shtml#FileRenamer) that I use that's pretty easy to get into. All you need to do is to choose the files that you need renamed, make sure the correct options are selected, and then to apply the changes.

It also has a handy "Undo" feature that you can use if the changes you just applied wasn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses PowerShell (on a single line):

`Get-ChildItem 'foo_bar*.jpg' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace 'foo_bar','foo bar'}`

Answer (score 1):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) comes with an extremely powerful multi-file rename utility among it's features. It's not free but there is a run-limited trail.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `move`:

```
move /y path\dfihsdfsdjsdfd.txt path\filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

"Advance renamer" free software for windows 10 is the best option to rename bulk files very easily.