# Add the extension, jpg, to a lot of files

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, file-management, ubuntu-8.10

I have a folder with a lot of folders with a lot of files and maybe more folders with more files, where some files lost their extension. I believe they are all jpgs, but I could be wrong. Any ideas how to re-add the extensions to all these files without doing it one by one?

I can do it on Windows 7 or Ubuntu 8.10.

Comment: This question will probably have an answer for you, as it is a bit similar : http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line

Comment: Did you check that you haven't turned off the display of the extension on those folders before embarking on the rename? Basic question I know, but you never know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it this way

```
find . -type f -iregex ".*[^\(\.jpg\)]" -exec mv "{}" "{}.jpg" ";"
```

Comment: Nice.  FWIW, a simpler method than **-iregex** is to use the negative of a *name* match:   **find . -type f \! -name '*.jpg'** (...).  Also, I try always to use an absolute path (*/bin/mv*) when using find/-exec.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it through cmd on windows.

> rename * *.jpg

Edit:
To apply to nested folders, you can use;

> for /r %x in (*) do rename "%x" *.jpg

Comment: Will that work recursively in all folders?

Comment: The command prompt still has its uses :)  Yeah DOS!

Comment: It will not - you'll need to use the 'for' command as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210413/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey; I've not come across "for" before! That's pretty nifty. I added that to the solution body.

Comment: +1 for a nice answer that didn't involve installing other operating systems or a heap of other programs.

Answer (score 2):

If using powershell is an option, then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251851/using-powershell-to-add-an-extension-to-files) from SO should be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**On Linux**

```
ls | while read file ; do mv $file $file.jpg; done
```

**On Windows**

I like to use [Rename4u](http://www.kellysoftware.com/software/Rename4u.asp) which is a freeware utility.

Comment: Just got to be careful not to append a .jpg extension to IMAGE001.jpg

Comment: Wouldn't the Linux version add the extension to all the files? Not all the files are missing the extension.

Comment: @J Pablo, .jpg.jpg still opens as a jpg ;)

In windows I'd do:
ren * *.jpg
but you could hack something together with a batch file to only do that if something didn't have an extension - I'm too lazy, myself. If it works, it works, right?

Answer (score 0):

[Extension Renamer](http://www.brothersoft.com/extension-renamer-download-41537.html) does the job.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Linux (or MSWindows w/CygWin)

If you wish to only add a suffix to files that are actually JPEGs, try this:

```
$ find . -type f  ! -name '*.jpg'  -print | while read f
> do case "$(file "$f")" in
>    *JPEG*) mv -iv "$f" "$f.jpg" ;;
>    esac
> done
```

Which will:

1. Print paths that are files w/o a **.jpg* suffix (**find**),
2. Check those files' contents (**file $f**),
3. For JPEG files, rename them with a _*.jpg* suffix.