# Tool to fix file names starting with =_iso-8859-1... in .eml file names?

Tags: windows, linux, email, grep, filenames

I have a folderful of E-Mails saved from an IMAP account that I dissolved.

The file name is the subject line of each E-Mail.

Now unfortunately, when a non-ASCII encoding is used, the subject line will look like they look internally - they will be prefixed with `=_` and the  encoding used:

```
=_UTF-8_Q_Auftragsbest=C3=A4tigung_(Kundennummer__)_=_20100819_150312_37.eml

=_windows-1252_Q_Best=E4tigung=3A_Wir_haben_Ihre_=_20100819_150310_28.eml
```

Does anybody know a tool that could be used to mass fix this on filesystem level?

A solution would have to 1. remove the `=_ENCODING` prefix and 2. if at all possible, convert the encoded characters in the file name to their proper filesystem equivalent Umlauts.

I'm on Windows 7 or XP, but I'd be ready to take this to a Linux VM because it is a *big* folder and an automated solution would be *great*.

Comment: Do you want to remove the reference to the encoding used in the filename ? I'm not sure what the eventual goal is. Perhaps use Bulk Rename ( http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php ) as mentioned in [Mass Rename Files](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line) @Pekka

Comment: Basically you need something like "convmv" with support for quoted-printable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built myself a PHP script. I thought I'd share it in the event somebody else ends up with a similar problem. It works for me and the encodings I needed (you may have to extend the encodings array).

The script converts MIME encoded file **names** recursively throughout the specified directory structure into UTF-8.

It doesn't produce entirely perfect results: There are several special characters that get doubly converted, or not at all. As far as I can see, this is the fault of the IMAP exporter or incorrect encoding info inside the E-Mail itself.

`mb_decode_mimeheader()` is the heart of the whole thing.

Released to the public domain; no warranty whatsoever. PHP 5.2 is required.

It should run on both CLI and through the web; I tested it in the browser.

Make backups before running scripts like this on your data.

```
<?php

 /* Directory to parse */
 $dir = "D:/IMAP";
 /* Extensions to parse. Leave empty for none */
 $extensions = array("eml");
 /* Set to true to actually run the renaming */
 define ("GO", true);

 /* No need to change past this point */  

 /* Output content type header if not in CLI */
 if (strtolower(php_sapi_name()) != "CLI")
  header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");


 $FixNames = new FixEmlNames($dir, $extensions);
 $FixNames->fixAll();



  class FixEmlNames
   {

     /* List of possible encodings here */
     private $encodings = array("iso-8859-1", "iso-8859-15", "windows-1252", "utf-8");
     /* Encoding Prefix. The exporter exports e.g. =_iso-8859-1_ with underscores 
        instead of question marks */
     private $encoding_prefix = "=_";
     /* Encoding postfix */
     private $encoding_postfix = "_";
     /* Temporary storage for files */
     private $files;
     /* Array of file extensions to process. Leave empty to parse all files and directories */
     private $extensions = array(); 
     /* Count of renamed files */
     private $count = 0;
     /* Count of failed renames */
     private $failed = 0;
     /* Count of skipped renames */
     private $skipped = 0;
     /* Transform forbidden characters in host OS */
     private $transform_characters = array(":" => "_", "?" => "_", ">" => "_");

     function __construct($dir, $extensions = array("eml"))
       { 

        $this->files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
        $this->extensions = $extensions;
       }

     function fixAll()
      {
        echo "Starting....\n";

        while($this->files->valid())
        {
         if (!$this->files->isDot())
          {

           $path = $this->files->key();
           $ext  = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           if ((count($this->extensions) == 0 ) or (in_array($ext, $this->extensions)))
            $this->renameOne($path);

          }
         $this->files->next();
        }

        echo "Done. ";

        /* Show stats */
        $status = array();

        if ($this->count > 0) $status[] = $this->count." OK";
        if ($this->failed > 0) $status[] = $this->failed." failed";
        if ($this->skipped > 0) $status[] = $this->skipped." skipped";

        echo implode(", ", $status);


      }

      function  renameOne($fullPath)
       {


          $filename = pathinfo($fullPath, PATHINFO_BASENAME); 
          $is_mime = false;

          // See whether file name is MIME encoded or not
          foreach ($this->encodings as $encoding)
           { if (stristr($filename, $this->encoding_prefix.$encoding.$this->encoding_postfix))
              $is_mime = true;
           }

           // No MIME encoding? Skip.
           if (!$is_mime)
            {
              # uncomment to see skipped files
              # echo "Skipped: $filename\n";
              $this->skipped++;
              return true;
            }

           mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
           $filename = str_replace("_", "?", $filename);  // Question marks were converted to underscores
           $filename = mb_decode_mimeheader($filename);
           $filename = str_replace("?", "_", $filename);  


           // Remove forbidden characters
           $filename = strtr($filename, $this->transform_characters);

          // Rename
          if (constant("GO") == true)
           {
            // We catch the error manually
            $old = error_reporting(0);
            $success = rename($fullPath, realpath(dirname($fullPath)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename); 
            error_reporting($old);        

          if ($success)
           {
           echo "OK: $filename\n";
           $this->count++; 
           return true;
           }
          else
           {
             $error = error_get_last();
             $message = $error["message"];
             $this->failed++;
             echo "Failed renaming $fullPath. Error message: ".$message."\n";
             return false;
           }
           }
           else
           {
             $this->count++;  
             echo "Simulation: $filename\n";
             return true;   
           }
       }


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're willing to move to linux, you could install a php server on it and make a fairly easy script to reencode the files. Degree of difficulty depends on if you've ever done any programming. You can reference these functions on [php.net](http://php.net)

These are the functions you would need

```
<?php

opendir  ( string $path  [, resource $context  ] )
readdir  ([ resource $dir_handle  ] )
file_get_contents(ENTER THE FILE NAMES HERE WITH A VARIABLE PASSED FROM readdir)
preg_replace(REGULAR EXPRESSION TO REMOVE THE =ENCODING part of the filename)
string mb_convert_encoding  ( string $str  , string $to_encoding  [, mixed $from_encoding  ] )
file_put_contents(THE NEW FILE NAME.eml)

?>
```

Comment: Cheers, I actually am a PHP programmer and will go down that route. However, decoding the characters is more tricky than just doing an mb_convert_encoding on them: It'll take something like mb_decode_mimeheader, still working on understanding how this stuff works. I'll post the solution as an answer when I'm done.

Comment: No upvote just because one does not need neither Linux nor a "PHP server" to run PHP scripts.

Comment: @Pekka - I'm Not high enough rep to post comment on your posted answer. Have you tried iconv() with TRANSLIT option to fix the characters that aren't encoding properly?  $output = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $input); It might work

Comment: @grawity - I've never run php scripts without a php server, how do you do it? Tried googling, but didn't come up with anything on the first few results. I mentioned linux because he said he was willing to move to it in his question and apache + php is easy to install on most linux distros.

Comment: @JMC the problem is garbled encodings that started much earlier than the export process. Therefore, it's impossible to know what is the start encoding - you could use `mb_detect_encoding` but it's not 100% reliable. That would be the next step for the script if somebody wants to take it further - I'm happy with how it does things now.

Comment: @JMC ...you run `php myscript.php` or `./myscript.php` on a command line, exactly the same way one would run Perl or Python programs.

Comment: @JMC Also, there is no such a thing as a "PHP server". There are only web (HTTP) servers, that can execute CGI programs (PHP or whatever).

Comment: @JMC Also, http://windows.php.net/