# Batch script to batch rename files or use a tool?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line)

i have some folders of files i want to rename. the general structure of the file is

```
/root
    /module 1
        /chapter 1
            /01 Intro.wmv
            /02 Topic.wmv
            ...
        /chapter 2
            /01 Intro.wmv
            /02 Topic.wmv
        /chapter 3
    /module 2
        /chapter 4
        /chapter 5
        /chapter 6
    ...
```

i want to batch rename files and move them to the `/root` directory with the specified format below

```
01 01 Intro.wmv
01 02 Topic.wmv
02 03 Intro.wmv
   ^ this is the chapter number
^ this is the module number
```

can i use a batch script to do this? i am on windows 7. or what tool can i use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Batch File Rename Utility](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/batchfilerenameu.html) . Its free

[image]

For other renaming tools go [here](http://www.snapfiles.com/freeware/system/fwfilerename.html) . Many of them are free

About Batch: I asked something similar in [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698511/moving-and-renaming-in-batch/3698806#3698806) for you, it should work with little modification

Answer (score 0):

It's certianly possible with a batch script.  You could use XCOPY, along with some scripting to check for folder contents, and use the names of the parent directories to form the file numbers.

It could be a worthwhile project if you want to learn about CMD scripting.  It would take me some time to come up with a script for you, so I won't, but I can answer any detailed questions that you may have, if you give it a go.

Comment: Possible? yes. Sensible? Depends. Renaming and moving manually would likely be quicker unless it's a LOT of files...

Comment: @torbengb: I agree, but it would be a pretty good way to learn batch scripting, which is a valuable skill for such file system work.