# Best tool to perform multiple renames under windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

Requirements:

- works for files/folders same time
- works on WinXP, Win7 (EDIT: 32 and 64 bit versions)
- supports regex
- has right click shell integration (I can select several files in folder and right click to rename only selected files in program)

Preferences:

- freeware
- no Commercials

Answer (score 5):

Although not right click  [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/projects.php) supports drag and drop of Files and Folders, an rule based renaming. It even includes the ability to include Pascal scripts for those really complex renaming jobs,  although I have always managed just with the built in rules

Answer (score 4):

[Bulk rename utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php).

Comment: Oh, did not know for this site, I will use it in future for questions like this! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I really like [RenameMaster](http://www.joejoesoft.com/cms/showpage.php?cid=108). It has an optional Explorer integration add-on (so you can right-click and send files/folders to the app).

Comment: This program seems OK, but explorer integration works only on 32-bit OS (mentioned on download page) ->  updating requirements

Answer (score 2):

I like [Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer/features). It's got every option I need and has a great interface. I don't think it has shell integration but it might work to put it in the "Send To" menu on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

While not just a renamer utility, [TotalCommander](http://ghisler.com/) has so far beaten every other tool I've seen. When you combine its `Find Files` feature with the `Multi-Rename Tool` (which has support for regexes & templates), the ability to use content plugins (there are plugins for almost every format out there) and you can even send the filenames to your preferred text editor for further processing. It's shareware, though.

A crazy example: You could search for all .PDF files in your computer with sizes between 100K and 2MB, not older than 6 months, with more than 3 pages, and rename them something to `[PublishedDate] Author - Title.pdf` (as read from the files' metadata), and send the filenames to Notepad++ for a final review and fixes, all in a matter of seconds.

And yes, it works also on folders.

Answer (score 0):

[Metamorphose](http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/) is one I've used before. I don't think it integrates into the shell, but it does support regex.