# Tool/method to reformat filenames

Tags: filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

I get lots of files from a variety of sources whose names I need to clean up for safe consumption on the web. Specifically, I want to change all the letters to lowercase and replace all spaces with dashes.

In other words, I want to convert

`This is a file that NEEDS conversion.txt`

to

`this-is-a-file-that-needs-conversion.txt`

And I'd like to do it in the most painless way possible. A tool that I can add to my right-click context menu would be ideal. I would prefer a Windows solution, but I have Ubuntu available to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool) and/or [Best tool to perform multiple rename under windows](http://superuser.com/questions/190674/best-tool-to-perform-multiple-rename-under-windows)

Comment: Do you need to do this for a large group of files (batch process) or is this just something you do regularly or frequently to a small number of files? If the former, this is a duplicate of the various bath file renaming questions, if the latter, I am not personally aware of similar questions.

Comment: It does indeed look like a duplicate. My search-fu apparently failed me.