# How to batch rename files in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

Is there any built-in support for batch renaming files in Windows? If not, what are some 3rd party tools which can do this?

Answer (score 3):

**[BulkRename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)** has both a GUI and a command line interface for renaming groups of files. Summary of features (from website):

> - Rename multiple files
> - Add, replace, and insert text into file names
> - Convert case, add numbers, remove or change file extensions
> - Change image EXIF meta data
> - Rename MP3 file ID3 tags

Answer (score 3):

If you want something built-in, you can select all the files you want to rename and then press F2 and rename the first one.  The files take the same name, but with a number suffix.

Comment: Note: it doesn't use the file creation or modification to order the files, it seems to sort them based on the original file names.

Answer (score 1):

**[File Renamer](http://www.webxpace.com/software/freeware.shtml)** is a GUI tool for batch renaming folders and files on Windows. Paraphrased description from the website:

> Numerate files sequentially, batch rename, replace strings, modify strings, change dates, modify file's attributes, etc. Drag and drop files and folders from explorer to its window. Supports creating your own more elaborated scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[Filemenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html)' has an Advanced Renamer utility for batch renames where you can use regexps too