# Bulk renaming files

Tags: windows, terminal, batch, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

So I have a series of files with the following format Their real file name followed by the date.

```
file_1_12DEC2011.pdf
file_2_12DEC2011.pdf
file_3_12DEC2011.pdf
file_4_12DEC2011.pdf
file_5_12DEC2011.pdf
```

I am trying to figure out How I can Increment the day by one day. For instance, this would be my desired result.

```
file_1_13DEC2011.pdf
file_2_13DEC2011.pdf
file_3_13DEC2011.pdf
file_4_13DEC2011.pdf
file_5_13DEC2011.pdf
```

Comment: Does it *have* to be from the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example case `ren *12DEC*.* ???????13*.*` from a command prompt should work.

Comment: That was just an example; they would have to edit and repeat the command for each and every day (which would quickly become problematic without some sort of recursion-preventing attention).

Answer (score 4):

[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is a great tool for this. Offers a choice of regexes, fixed index changes (that is what you should go for probably) and a host of other options.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not have to be a command-line tool, then my advanced file-renaming program of choice is Cylog’s [Wildren](http://www.cylog.org/utilities/wildrename.jsp). In your case, you would combine the regular-expression function with the counter function. It can also simulate the rename operations so that you can check if your parameters are correct before doing it for real.