# I need to rename a group of numbered files, but modify the number + 5. How?

Tags: batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

I have a group of 47 .mp3 files that are being used for a multimedia project that are named 01.mp3 - 47.mp3 Every file should really have a name that is that number + 5, so that 02.mp3 should really be 07.mp3 The renamed files can have some sort of prefix + the number, or can be written to a new folder as to not interfere with the existing files.

I have Ubnutu and Windows at my disposal.. Can someone suggest an approach to this?

Comment: Try bulkrename...http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Screenshots.php

Comment: I'll have to play around with this tomorrow, but you should be able to easily pull something off with a for loop in bash.

Comment: Since you're adding, start at the end and count down, so you don't have to deal with clashes between new and old names.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in awk with a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    regex = "[0-9]+"
    print "mkdir new"
}
{
    if (match($8,regex)) {
        before = substr($8,1,RSTART-1);
        pattern = substr($8,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        newnumber = pattern + 5
        after = substr($8,RSTART+RLENGTH);
        printf("mv %s new/%s%.2d%s\n", $8, before, newnumber, after);
    }
}
```

Assuming you had a folder containing the following files:

```
foo01
foo02
foo03
foo04
foo05
bar10.txt
bar11.txt
bar12.txt
bar13.txt
rename.awk
```

If you executed the command `ls -l|./rename.awk|sh` you would then have:

```
new/foo06
new/foo07
new/foo08
new/foo09
new/foo10
new/bar15.txt
new/bar16.txt
new/bar17.txt
new/bar18.txt
rename.awk
```

You can of course modify the script or shell command to only rename files fitting a certain pattern or increment by a different amount.

Comment: This looked like the easiest approach, but there maybe a syntax issue. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. Here's what was displayed after I ran the script:

myname@X201:~/Dropbox/Eye Rhymes Web/Audio$ sh rename.sh
rename.sh: 2: BEGIN: not found
rename.sh: 3: regex: not found
Warning: unknown mime-type for "mkdir new" -- using
"application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "mkdir new"
rename.sh: 5: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
myname@X201:~/Dropbox/Eye Rhymes Web/Audio$

Comment: @Kendor: It might be due to the location of the awk interpreter on your system. I created this script on a shell account off of my shared hosting account, and on that system, awk was located at `/usr/bin/awk`. However, the usual location for `awk` is `/bin/awk`, _I think_. You can check on your system by running `which awk`, then change the first line in the script to match the location displayed.

Comment: @Kendor: you ran `sh` on an awk script.  If you'd made the file executable (with `chmod`), and run it, it would have invoked awk through the `#!` mechanism.  Instead, you ran `sh` on it, and it's not a valid `sh` script.