# How to remove Soundcloud numbers from MP3 files?

Tags: mp3, music, mp3-player

I used jDownloader to download a bunch of songs from Soundcloud but each MP3 has a underscore followed by a unique set of numbers.

> Song1_92839839.mp3
>
> _92839339 Song2.mp3
>
> Song _92835559 Three.mp3

How can I remove the underscore and numbers from each MP3?

I believe each number is between 8 - 10 digits but I could be wrong.

Comment: What OS are you on? Will greatly impact the answer...

Comment: How much is a "Bunch"?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows, you need a third party utility, since there's nothing on the command line that'll do this in one shot.

[Another question](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files) suggests a "[bulk rename utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/)".

If you're on Linux, you probably have access to a command called `rename`.

Now let's look at your filenames - your examples show that all of the bad stuff in the name **looks identical**, that is, an underscore followed by numbers, but they're in different places in the name.

For something like this, that's a consistent type of problem in a varying location, you would to construct a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to target the junk data.

Since it's just an underscore and a bunch of numbers, that would be easy. The regex will look like this: `_\d+`.

This means an underscore, and any digit (`\d`), 1 or more times (`+`).

The bulk rename utility for Windows has a regex option built in - look at the top left:

[image: Bulk rename utility GUI]

You'd place the regex in the "match" box, leave the replacement blank, and hit Rename!

**JUST IN CASE: Make a copy of the folder first.**

The Linux rename command would need the command written like:

```
rename 's/_\d+//g' *.mp3
```

(**s**earch for any text matching the regex and replace it with nothing, and do this **g**lobally, or as many times as necessary)