# Get first two strings of each filename in a directory as a txt file

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, parsing, directory-listing

I need to clean up strings like this (where I read in a group of image names), where I only want the first two strings (currently I'm using, in Windows 7 cmd line - dir /a/b/p > textfile.txt):

- Acaena inermis no barbs dbot_25Dec15_40.JPG
- Coprosma Taiko PB121944 invbot.rs.JPG
- Cortaderia richardii InvBot P6260038.JPG
- Anemanthele lessoniana LIC.nestmaker.CC BY-SA 2.0.jpg
- Myosotidium hort ibot PB109882 sqr rs.JPG

to look like this (Word space word and strip the rest):

- Acaena inermis
- Coprosma Taiko
- Cortaderia richardii
- Anemanthele lessoniana
- Myosotidium hort

Is there a way using either cmd or batch to simplify this? Normally there would be 15 files parsed each time I do this. I'm hardly a cmd-line guru!

Comment: Just to clarify things, are you looking to rename files to word space word? without the extension even?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mass rename files?](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files)

Comment: One of the answers lists PowerGrep which seems to also replace regex inside files. That's one you may want to use, or use something like Notepad++ where you can find/replace using regex inside a textfile.

Comment: Thanks very much LPChip, I'll look at these tomorrow and get back here

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried with the batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from command line:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %g in (textfile.txt) do @for /F "tokens=1,2" %G in ("%~ng") do @if not "%H"=="" echo(%G %H
```

or start from scratch

```
for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /A/B/S') do @for /F "tokens=1,2" %G in ("%~ng") do @if not "%H"=="" echo(%G %H
```

You need to double `%` percent signs in `for` loop variable names in a batch file as follows:

```
@echo OFF
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in (textfile.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("%%~ng") do if not "%%H"=="" echo(%%G %%H
)
```

or

```
@echo OFF
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /A/B/S') do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("%%~ng") do if not "%%H"=="" echo(%%G %%H
)
```

To redirect output to a plain text file `taxons.txt` (note additional `()` parentheses:

```
>taxons.txt (for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /A/B/S') do @for /F "tokens=1,2" %G in ("%~ng") do @if not "%H"=="" echo(%G %H)
```

or in a batch script:

```
@echo OFF
>taxons.txt (
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /A/B/S') do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("%%~ng") do @if not "%%H"=="" echo(%%G %%H
)
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~ng` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>`, `2>1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thanks very very much JosephZ, that probably saves me half an hour a day! and it does everything at the start in cmd.

I used your "start from scratch" line and added >> textfile2.txt

Comment: graphical result - [link] (http://i.imgur.com/nZS7HEi.jpg)_italic_ **bold** `code`

Answer (score 1):

Download the free text editor called Notepad++

Open your textfile.

Press CTRL-H to open the find and replace dialog.

At the bottom left, check `Regular Expression`

In Find: enter `^(.+?[ ].+?)[ ].+$`
In Replace: enter `$1`

This code will assume that after the 2nd word a space is present. If there is another char there, such as a _ or - replace the second [ ] with [ _-] (listing whatever char there is). Keep in mind that if you have this text part as the word too, it will cut off there in other searches.

Comment: And thanks for giving me a simple intro to Regular Expression in N++